# List all Schedule Query with user who created

Tags: google-bigquery

I use `bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=asia-southeast-1 --format json` without `max-results` to list all the schedule query existing.
It should returns [ListTransferConfigsResponse](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/ListTransferConfigsResponse) having [TransferConfig](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig) Obj inside but it's not. I need "OwnerInfo" which has the email of the user. Did google write missing docs? I want to call 1 api to get all info. Any help?

Comment: After doing [transferConfig.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/list), get the transferConfig name. Call [transferConfig.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/get) and pass the transferConfig name. The response should contain "OwnerInfo".

Comment: But I want to call API once, cause of the number of schedule queries and the changing of owner each day so we have to call all over again.